# Post json data to symfony2 controller

Tags: jquery, json, controller, symfony-2.6

so I'm trying to post json data to a symfony controller. I've

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit-button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "/registerTransaction",  
            data: { "data" : 'test' },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);              
            },
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json'
        }); 
    });
});
```

and for the controller

```
<?php

namespace Test\MyBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class TransactionController extends Controller
{
    public function registerTransactionAction()
    {
        $request = $this->container->get('request');
        $data = $request->get('data');
        var_dump($data);
        die;
    }
}
```

My routing.yml is

```
test_my_register:
    path:     /registerTransaction
    defaults: { _controller: TestMyBundle:Transaction:registerTransaction }
```

But all I get is null for response. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to change

```
data: { "data" : 'test' },
```

to

```
data: '{ "data" : 'test' }',
```

and use in the controller

```
$data = $this->get("request")->getContent();
if(!empty($data)) {
    $params = json_decode($data, true);
}
```